# Get seconds and milliseconds from date/time in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime, time

Is there a way break out the seconds and milliseconds from a date time field in a formula field?

**WHY:** 
I want our crew people to use check-in and check-out from their mobile device.  However, if they forget to check in or don't have service, I need to give them the ability to manually override the time.  I want the supervisor to be able to identify if the device did it vs end user.  I can create a formula field that looks at milliseconds and if they are 0 then I would assume the date was modified manually.

Comment: You can via `Apex`...

Comment: After looking at it deeper, I'm not 100% sure the system actually stores millisecond values...

Comment: I was able to parse it out when creating the date by using string.valueOf(checkintime.getTime/1000).left(3) however, the UI didn't have the precision to chop it off on edit, so it just left it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the Griffin's answer is incorrect (should be `RIGHT` instead of `LEFT`).

This formula will give you the seconds as a number.  As Griffin's answer states, you must use apex if you need milliseconds.

```
VALUE(
    LEFT(
        RIGHT(
            TEXT(now())
        ,3)
    ,2)
)
```

Comment: My formula was not incorrect. The use case was checking for 0 seconds. Your formula does not actually meet the use case it simply returns the number of seconds it does not incorporate the true/false statement.

Comment: @Griffin actually your formula is incorrect.  LEFT(3) returns the first 3 characters for the year in the date part (201), not the time

Comment: You are correct and I retract my statement. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest you can get is in seconds and even that involves some gymnastics. In order to check the seconds on a DateTime field you can do the following:

```
IF((RIGHT(TEXT(TODAY()),3) == '00Z'),true,false);
```

This would return true of the seconds are 0 and false if the seconds are anything but. I don't recommend this seeing as you really have a 1/60 change instead of the 1/6000 you would if milliseconds were included.

Now you could use Apex. There it's pretty simple.

```
Datetime yourDate = Datetime.time();
Integer seconds = yourDate.second();
Integer milliseconds = yourDate.millisecond();

Boolean manualUpdate = false;

if(seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0){
        manualUpdate = true;
}
```

Further DateTime function can be found [in documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm).

Comment: I was trying this:  system.debug(string.valueOf(a.check_in_time__c.getTime()/1000).left(3));  However, what is your milliseconds variable?

Comment: @tjcinnamon Oops! My bad. I updated it so it should work. I'm using built in Datetime functions

Comment: When I use millisecond() it always returns 0

Comment: When I use (string.valueOf(a.check_in_time__c.getTime()/1000).left(3), the milliseconds don't change when I manually edit the time from the UI

Comment: All I needed to do was compare the create date time to the check-in time.  That should be suffiencent enough.  There are rare circumstances where an employee could game the system where if the time entry allowed seconds and the create date was created on 00 seconds.  But this should be sufficnet

Comment: @tjcinnamon I don't think Salesforce has the whole DateTime thing down right now. It's doing some Javascript kinda stuff (Context: https://goo.gl/wyk4f1)

Comment: 100% agree.  Even the data entry is cumbersome on it.  Users get the calendar and have to click to the right spot to change the time.  They also don't have just a time field.  My users are pretty frustrated with that

Comment: @tjcinnamon If you want to not use the calendar I highly recommend making a VF component you can stick on pages that has all the options you want. Then you can build an acceptable DateTime string using Javascript (easier than it sounds) I'm not sure about your set up but this'll likely be a big quick win.

Comment: I like your style.  The js I could probably do fairly easy but the component would be new.  I'll call it extra credit toward the end

Comment: @tjcinnamon Component will just let you use it in multiple places (although I'm still not sure how flexible this can be). If you implement it here all you have to do is abstract it about and create a component VF thing. I inflate my stories by 30 minutes and build up this time buffer so by the end up the sprint I can fix stupid things I've found. I hoard these time buffers like old ladies hoard pennies. It's sad but so much of our code base needs work and management only wants new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

While NSjonas's answer does get you the correct result it does not follow Salesforce best practices and is thus incorrect.

Users should minimize the number of functions being used when possible. To do this the proper formula should be:

```
VALUE(
    MID(
        TEXT(NOW())
    ,18,2)
)
```

To solve the use case or for how to work with milliseconds please refer to my original answer.